# Autogenerate a field value during JAXB unmarshalling

Tags: jaxb

Say, I have a XML as below:

```
<MyBooks>
    <book>
        <author>some author</author>
        <name>Book A</name>
    </book>
    <book>
        <author>some other author</author>
        <name>Book B</name>
    </book>
</MyBooks>
```

....and I want a class like this to represent each *book*:

```
class Book{
    String id;
    String author;
    String name;
}
```

While using JAXB, can we set an auto-generated unique id to the "id" field for each book object...during un-marshalling itself? (I don't want the supplier of the XML to bear the pain of adding an "id" for each book in the XML).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement this method in your `Book` class. Use it to create the id you want. (It is not part of an interface, just match the signature)

```
 //This method is called after all the properties (except IDREF) are unmarshalled for this object,
 //but before this object is set to the parent object.
 void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller, Object parent);
```